# Can anyone simplify this MySQL table relationship for polls?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table polls (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key, 
  created datetime, 
  modified datetime
);

create table quizzes (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);

create table questions (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  model varchar(255) not null, -- Poll or Quiz, in this scenario
  foreign_key integer not null,
  question varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);

create table answers (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  question_id integer not null,
  answer varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified datetime
);
```

Can anyone make it more simpler(shorter) and meaningful than this for polls and quiz table ?

Here is another idea, which is better ? =>

```
| polls | CREATE TABLE `polls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `mark` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |



| pollanswers | CREATE TABLE `pollanswers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `poll_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `percentage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `correct` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `mark` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: I'm not seeing why you need separate polls and quizzes table, isn't that redundant with what is in the questions table?

Comment: If it's a MySql table, why the sql-server and postgresql tags?

Comment: The field would be different, the structure would be same for sql-server or postgresql , right ?

Comment: Quick point; your `created` column is pretty useless unless you enforce a not null for this as well, and you `modified` column should be a default so you don't actually need to do anything to it.

Comment: polls and quizzes tables can be merged into single table and if you really need to track whether its poll or quiz like you might have specific constraints for both you can add type column and make one table say activity. type can be quiz or  poll

Comment: Someone please post complete create statement for tables.

Comment: No, the entire table relationship can be different from what i posted.  Post your own table relationship.

Comment: I changed the original question/post. Which is better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, always name your tables in the singular. This is because a "table definition" is actually the definition for each row - *one* row (ie singular). Also, it reads more naturally: `quiz.id` makes sense - the id of the quiz, but `quizzes.id` is what? The id of the quizzes? No.

To answer your question, you should definitely merge poll and quiz into one table. The tip off is they have the same definition. If you need to distinguish between the two, have a boolean column. Let's call it quiz.

You should also name your foreign keys as 'table_id', eg 'quiz_id'.

You should probably give a name to your quizzes.

In mysql, the `timestamp` data type *automatically* updates whenever you change something in the row. It's pretty handy - saves adding `now()` to every update/insert value set.

IMHO your tables should be:

```
create table quiz (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  created datetime,
  modified timestamp,
  name text,
  is_poll boolean not null default false
);

create table question (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  quiz_id integer not null references quiz,
  question varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified timestamp
);

create table answer (
  id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
  question_id integer not null references question,
  answer varchar(255) not null,
  created datetime,
  modified timestamp
);
```

Comment: I disagree with your singular rule. Tables are collections of objects and therefore must be plural. In your example `quiz.id` does not make sense because the attribute `id` is unique and therefore will refer to only one quiz. But when we talk about the quizzes stored in the quizzes table like, for example, `SELECT quizzes.name`, `WHERE quizzes.modified`, `SELECT * FROM quizzes`, it makes perfect sense to talk in plural since a resultset may contain more than one quiz. When I talk I say, hand me over those quizzes, I don't say hand me over those quiz.

Comment: @Ben You are contradicting yourself! `quiz.id` *does* refer to only one quiz! That's the whole point! I will concede that `SELECT * FROM quizzes` sounds natural, but in all other contexts, like `WHERE quiz.id = 1` etc, the singular is the *only* choice that sounds sane. Consider that each row is like a persisted version of an object. You don't name object classes in the plural, so don't name the row class (which is the table def) in the plural.

Comment: but it does sound natural! "Hand me over the quizzes, those quizzes that have the name test written on them" we need to talk in plural since we're asking for a resulset, a collection of items, not just one item. Again, `quiz.id = 1` sounds natural because the id is unique an will be referring to only one single quiz. But what about the name or the score `SELECT FROM quizzes WHERE score > 0` seems natural to me since I'll be expecting   several quizzes, not just one. `SELECT FROM quizzes WHERE id = 1` sounds like "hand me those quizzes that have the id 1" which is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm a different Ben and I agree with the first one @Bohemian. I much prefer naming tables in the plural.

Comment: And as for readability, one can always use aliases. I usually shorten table name to 1-2 letters. `SELECT * FROM questions q, users.u WHERE q.user_id = u.id`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a perfect organization. The only thing is , you can save on 'created' and 'modified' fields in polls and quizzes tables leaving them in 'questions' only and only if 'questions' is inserted at the same time that 'poll' or 'quiz'  .....

personally for me, looks like too much date fields. I wouldn't use them, but the organization you put is valid. If you would post your data usage for this problem, we could comment more.

Comment: ohh, and btw, if you use 1 field in the table polls or quizes it is much more disk/memory overhead than adding those fields into 'questions'

Comment: No, the entire table relationship can be different from what i posted.  Post your own table relationship.

Comment: I changed the original question/post. Which is better ?